# BDD with cucumber: how to generate steps?

Tags: cucumber

I've an empty java gradle project:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java8:5.4.0'
    testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:5.4.0'
}
```

Wrote a *.feature file:

Feature: All PIN variations

```
Scenario: *********************
    Given **************
    When ******************* ****
    Then  ************************
```

I've read from tutorials (a lot of them in the internet): I need to somehow generate steps. I'm using IntellijIdea, I wanna promote nothing, just what should I do? I guess I need to use some tool/plugin, so please just advise to me a direction where to search and best practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The JetBrains documentation provides a bulletproof guide for this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/cucumber-support.html). If you've followed the setup properly, creating a step from a feature file is as simple as hovering over the step and pressing `Option + Enter` on your keyboard [as also mentioned in their documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-step-definition.html#create-step-def).